# Noise and Lines Issue in K-means Clustering with Silhouette Method for Color Application

Tags: python, image-processing, k-means

I am currently working with the K-means clustering algorithm combined with the silhouette method to determine the optimal k-value for my dataset. My goal is to apply distinct colors to the generated clusters. However, when I assign the colors, I notice some noise and faint lines within the clusters. These seem to be caused by colors that have been clustered but have a very low percentage in the dataset.

To address this, I implemented a method to exclude colors from clustering if they fall below a certain percentage threshold. However, even after this adjustment, the output still shows noise, especially noticeable at the borders of the clusters. I've attached an image for reference.

Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue, ensuring a smoother color application without the noise? I appreciate any assistance!

[ORIGINAL IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwuVF.png)

[CLUSTERED IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tge9k.png)

[COLOR MODIFIED IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzYJa.png)

Process to get clustered image

```
def optimal_k_using_silhouette(image):
    lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
    data = sample_pixels(lab_image)
    range_n_clusters = list(range(2, 7))
    silhouette_avgs = []
    for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:
        clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=10, n_init=10)
        cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(data)
        silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(data, cluster_labels)
        silhouette_avgs.append(silhouette_avg)

    best_k = range_n_clusters[np.argmax(silhouette_avgs)]
    best_clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=best_k, random_state=10, 
n_init=10).fit(data)

    valid_clusters = get_valid_clusters(best_clusterer, 
lab_image.reshape(-1, 3))
    best_clusterer.cluster_centers_ = 
best_clusterer.cluster_centers_[valid_clusters]
    best_clusterer.n_clusters = len(valid_clusters)

 return best_clusterer
```

then we save ssagments
then we save colors with labels

here is how i modified the colors

```
@app.route("/modify_colors", methods=["POST"])
def modify_colors():
    modified_colors = []
    for i in range(len(session['colors_bgr'])):
        r = int(request.form.get(f'color_{i}_r'))
        g = int(request.form.get(f'color_{i}_g'))
        b = int(request.form.get(f'color_{i}_b'))
        modified_colors.append((b, g, r))

    segmented_image_path = "static/segmented_image.png"
    segmented_img, alpha_channel = 
upscale_and_smooth(segmented_image_path, desired_width=1600)
    print("Segmented Image Shape:", segmented_img.shape)

    replaced_image = replace_colors(segmented_img, 
session['colors_bgr'], modified_colors)
    print("Replaced Image Shape:", replaced_image.shape)

    # Blend the images at the borders
    replaced_image = blend_at_borders(segmented_img, replaced_image)

    if alpha_channel is not None:
        replaced_image = cv2.merge([replaced_image, alpha_channel])
    cv2.imwrite('static/segmented_image_modified.png', replaced_image)
    session['segmented_image_path'] = 
'static/segmented_image_modified.png'  # Update the path in session
    return render_template('result_modified.html', 
image_path=session['segmented_image_path'])
```

Comment: Please post a [mre] of your code, so we know what you did. Your explanation leaves a lot of gaps, code is always the best way to communicate here. Your clustered image looks fine, but I don’t know how you got to the 3rd image, so can’t tell you how to improve that step.

Comment: please check, i have updateed with code.

Comment: i have chnaged all rgb to green to show the noice

Comment: The code you posted loads a `static/segmented_image.png`. I presume this is the 2nd image of the three linked images. That image has intermediate intensities at edges. It is probably not a good representation to do a 1:1 color mapping on. Instead, find the nearest centroid for each pixel, and assign its color.